# Downcasting an entire array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

In Unity I am trying to detect all the components of type text on an object

```
this.GetComponents(typeof(Text))
```

but it returns an array of components.
Since I know every component must be of type text I should be able to downcast it.
I tried to explicit cast it

```
Text[] a = (Text[])this.GetComponents(typeof(Text));
```

but that didn't work.
Text is a derived class of component, but I don't know how to downcast the array so I can use the methods that are associated with type text. Can someone show me how I can convert the array to one of the type Text?

Comment: [`OfType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0) should be what you're looking for

Comment: Actually there can only be one component of type UIElement on a GameObject anyway ... so this shouldn't be working at all ...

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponents.html), you can use the generic method `GetComponents` without needing to type cast each.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        HingeJoint[] hinges = GetComponents<HingeJoint>();
        for (int i = 0; i < hinges.Length; i++)
        {
            hinges[i].useSpring = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the *generic* syntax: `this.GetComponents<Text>()`. That returns a `Text[]` so no need to cast anymore.